# How can I see my browsing history on Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

As a registered user I can see the list of articles I read in the iOS app on my phone. How can I see the same on the desktop?

It would be really useful to have one merged list with all viewed articles from any places I logged in to Wikipedia (desktop and mobile app).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wikimedia's [**Reading list browser extension**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Apps/Reading_list_browser_extension), though recent Chrome Web Store reviews say that it is broken and [to use an unofficial alternative](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wikipedia-reading-lists/nngeaaogaldpfiedmmpicdnoddglbkmi).